# How do you modify liveness and readiness probe parameters?

Tags: containers, openshift, rhel, kubernetes-pod

I am running Red Hat OCP on a cluster with 5 worker nodes. A lot of my pods will timeout and crash because they fail liveness and readiness probes. I see everywhere people talking about changing the parameters (e.g. timeoutSeconds, periodSeconds, initialDelaySeconds) but I am not able to modify these values in either the OCP console or the terminal. How do I modify these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't edit the liveness and readiness parameters of the pod (at least while it's running), which is most likely a defense mechanism against crashing services. What you have to do is edit the deployment or replica set that deployed the pod.

```
oc edit deploy <my_deployment>
```

One of two things will occur:
1. The pod will restart automatically
2. You manually delete the pod and it will reinitialize with the new configuration

Reference here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your Pod's template into the DeploymentConfig (see [application_health](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/application_health.html), [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes)'s description of parameters).

In addition, you can do it in the WebConsole (Deployment > Actions > Edit Heath Checks) or use 'oc set probe' (use 'oc set probe --help' for more details), e.g.:

```
oc set probe dc/test --readiness --get-url=http://:8080/health
```